# Custom Transition Between Navigation Controllers

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

I want to have a custom transition between two navigation controllers. Let's call the first one `sourceController` and the other one `detailNavController`.

Here's my code:

```
NewEntryViewController *viewController = [[NewEntryViewController alloc] 
                                                                  initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
viewController.parentController = self;

UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                                  initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:detailNavController animated:NO];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:sourceController.view cache:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

`SourceController` was first presented modally, that's why I'm presenting `detailNavController` modally. The problem with this code is that the animation takes place, but sourceController is still on top of the new `detailNavController`. What I would like to achieve is to have the animation and then dismiss `sourceController` and have `detailNavController` displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution for this, here's the updated code:

```
- (void)createNewEntryWithAnimation
{
    // before calling this method I dismissed sourceController without animation
    NewEntryViewController *viewController = [[NewEntryViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    viewController.parentController = self;

    UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                                   initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:detailNavController animated:NO];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:viewController.view.window cache:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I had to use cache:NO, otherwise the transition wasn't smooth.